# Adding JSON results to JavaScript list

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have created a script to call a page, which returns a list of date strings via JSON. How do I add these dates to an array that I've created?

```
var bookedDates= [];
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Ajax/getBooked",
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            alert("success");
            //Add results to list here?
        }
    });
});
```

I'm new to JavaScript.

Comment: Can you give us a sample of the JSON response?

Comment: Here you go: ["2015-06-15","2015-06-16","2015-06-17","2015-06-20","2015-06-22","2015-06-23"]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Array.prototype.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

> The concat() method returns a new array comprised of the array on which it is called joined with the array(s) and/or value(s) provided as arguments.
>
> > var new_array = old_array.concat(value1[, value2[, ...[, valueN]]])

*Code*

```
bookedDates = bookedDates.concat(response)
```

---

Or, Use [Array.prototype.push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

> The push() method adds one or more elements to the end of an array and returns the new length of the array

*Code*

```
Array.prototype.push.apply(bookedDates, response);
```

Comment: Thanks you. I've to use the concat method. How do i use an alert to display the contents of my array, to test that it has worked? Many thanks

Comment: Don't worry, done it. Works a treat. Thanks so much.